# required help to fetch list of users from Azure AD using "Get-AzureADUser"

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, export

Can anyone help me with this?

I have a list of email IDs located in my **D:\Script\userlist.txt(1000+ Users)**. I would like to get their **user principal ID/Location ID and email ID from Azure AD**(For those 1000 users alone since we have a lot of users present in AD) using the PowerShell command.

Comment: Hi sathish, Try with using  the `Filter` in the  `Get-AzureADUser` :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0   refer these  documents  may helps you 
 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/995c2a14-c576-4653-b7f3-28b32902677c/get-multiple-ad-users-based-on-userprincipalname-and-then-export-them-into-csv-file?forum=winserverpowershell , https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-managing-users-via-the-azure-active-directory/ba-p/961128

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried, what failed, what worked. If you received error messages add these to the question too. As it is now, you are simply asking someone to write your code, but SO is meant to help people with **their** code.

Comment: **The command I tried is below, I'm looking for a similar one to fetch from Azure AD**
$Users = @{}
Get-Content 'D:\scripts\Users.txt' | ForEach-Object { $Users[$_] = $true }
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties EmailAddress,userPrincipalName | Where-Object { $Users.ContainsKey($_.SamAccountName) } | Select-Object EmailAddress,userPrincipalName | Export-Csv 'D:\scripts\your.csv' -NoType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

You can use the below PowerShell command to get the list of Azure AD users details from the user’s email:

```
Get-Content ' D:\Script\userlist.txt' | ForEach-Object {Get-AzureADUser -Filter "mail eq '$_'" | select userPrincipalName,mail,usageLocation} | export-csv ' D:\scripts\your.csv'
```

[image]

Comment: This one works but I'm not getting the UPN for all the users still checking on this... Are we missing anything???